# Getting an Invalid Qualifier error. I am trying to print the common brands from a workbook to another with help of an array

Tags: excel, vba

The code when run shows no error but no values are being printed:

```
Sub HouseOfCommons()

Dim filePath As String
filePath = "D:\"
Dim Brands(100) As String
Dim QuesRange(4) As String

QuesRange(0) = "A10:F125"

QuesRange(1) = "A137:F254"

QuesRange(2) = "A266:F307"

QuesRange(3) = "A319:F362"

QuesRange(4) = "A373: F415"

Dim inputx As String
inputx = InputBox("Enter the brand")



For I = 0 To 4
    Workbooks.Open (filePath + "JP_CP_2019Q3_Data Tables.xlsx")
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("P_2_3w").Select
    If (Workbooks("JP_CP_2019Q3_Data Tables.xlsx").Worksheets("P_2_3w").Range("A137:A500").Find(inputx)) = True Then
        If (Brands.Contains(inputx)) = False Then
        Brands.Add (inputx)
        For x = 1 To UBound(Brands)
        Workbooks.Open ("D:\InProcess.xlsm")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Value(I, 1) = inputx
        Next x
        End If
    End If
Next I
```

End Sub

The code should store the common brands into an array and print them in a separate workbook called "InProcess.xlsm"

Comment: `.Contains` is .Net syntax I think - that doesn't work in VBA.  In VBA you can use `Application.Match()` to find out if a value is in an array, or use a `Scripting.Dictionary` instead of an array.

Comment: I am using "Brands" as a collection now instead of an array, It shows no error but the values are not being printed on the second workbook.

Answer (score 1):

You're using .NET syntax which is not supported in VBA:

```
If (Brands.Contains(inputx)) = False Then
```

possible replacement:

```
If IsError(Application.Match(inputx, Brands, 0)) Then
```

Your code seems to have other problems but without knowing what it's supposed to do it's difficult to offer suggested fixes.

Comment: "If IsError(Application.Match(inputx, Brands, 0)) Then
            Brands.Add (inputx)" It still shows the error Invalid Qualifier marking "Brands", in "Brands.Add". Anyways, Thanks

Comment: There is no `Array.Add()` method in VBA.  It's unclear why you even have this in the loop - there is only ever one single `inputx` value collected, so what is the purpose of the array ?

Comment: inputx takes a user input, stores it in the array and if it is unique, it prints it.

Comment: It will always be unique, because your array is always empty when you test.